# Install windows XP from USB Flash drive on netbook

Tags: windows-xp, installation, boot, netbook

I need to install Windows XP on netbook.

I found utility which helps me to create USB flash boot drive.

But there is a problem when format or not drive screen is appear. There are not visible hdd on it. I found on one forum that need to change in BIOS some data for HDD from 'AHCI' to 'IDE'. And also need to add HDD drivers to boot flash drive.

So can anybody explain how to add drivers to boot flash?
And is there true that HDD not visible because some data (...HDD from 'AHCI' to 'IDE'...) in BIOS is changed?

Thanks

**LastUpdate:**

so it looks like that i decide this problem, what i do. I get Windows XP cd and copy all data to folder, then i found patch in internet which integrate AHCI (SATA) drivers with original windows distributive and after patching was done i create bootable usb flash drive, and bingo my acer aspire one show me his HDD))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the netbook is using a sata hard disk controller.  You need to find out what type of controller it is from the manufacturers website and download the appropriate XP drivers.

Its been so long since I installed XP, but if I remember correctly during the text phase of the installation process, there is a notification at the bottom that says press F6 to install 3rd party device drivers.  The installation will ask for the location of those files, and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks, for answer. what about drivers it's enough to add them only to usb or i need to add them to flash boot drive in another way?

Comment: they just need to be readable by WinXP.  Just extract them to a folder on the usb drive.  Or even another USB thumb drive.

Comment: Keltari thanks i decided this problem, Now it works great. Thanx. I wrote results in LastUpdate.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for all. Maybe this question will be helpfull for smb.

Answer (score 1):

Since your on a netbook, you do not need third party SATA Drivers, since you must be having a generic SATA controller which most Operating Systems pick up. And you must be having a SATA hard drive from a standard vendor like Hitachi or Toshiba or WDC or Seagate.

You just need to swap the setting from AHCI to IDE from BIOS, and that is pretty much it. I am attaching a screenshot, so you know what your actually finding. Fixed one of friend's laptop with the same problem.

[image: AHCI to IDE in BIOS]

Comment: aliasgar thanks, i already found this options and have been changed to IDE Mode. After that i boot from USB Flash Drive and nothing happend. It looks like that it trying to boot from HDD. But when i boot from usb while AHCI is selected my flash drive boot is ok but haven't seen HDD.

Comment: how did u make your USB bootable, which tutorial / tool did you use? USB drive should boot fine on IDE mode also, doesn't matter if it thinks it's a hard drive.

Comment: more than likely Win XP will not have the SATA drivers

Comment: i use WinSetupFromusb_1-0 with this tutor http://myeeeguides.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/winsetupfromusb-install-windows-xp-from-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: so it looks like that i decide this problem, what i do. I get Windows XP cd and copy all data to folder, then i found patch in internet which integrate AHCI (SATA) drivers with original windows distributive and after patching was done i create bootable usb flash drive, and bingo my acer aspire one show me his HDD))

Answer (score 1):

Independently whether your system is running in IDE or AHCI mode you have to integrate the appropriate drivers into your XP installation because AHCI is not supported by a plain XP setup and if the IDE/SATA controller is newer than Windows XP the required drivers are also missing.

A very easy way for modifying an XP setup is using [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com). It allows you to integrate the drivers so that they are automatically loaded when XP setup is started.

The only alternative would be to integrate the drivers while setup is running by pressing F6 - but that requires the drivers to be present on a floppy. If your system does not have  a floppy drive the driver integration is the only option.